# How can I handle split packages in automatic modules?

Tags: maven, maven-compiler-plugin, java-9, java-platform-module-system

I am currently testing to migrate an existing application to Jigsaw Modules. One of my modules uses ElasticSearch along with its Groovy Plugin.

- org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch
- org.elasticsearch.module:lang-groovy

Unfortunately, they share a split package, so `mvn install` gives me:

> x reads package org.elasticsearch.script.groovy from both lang.groovy and elasticsearch

once for each required module in the descriptor, where x is the name of each module.

I assume that a newer elasticsearch version will have eliminated the split package by the time Java 9 is final, but is there generally a way to handle split packages in legacy dependencies?

I was hoping to be able to have those on the the classpath instead of the module path, but after reading [this conversation on the mailing list](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@maven.apache.org/msg138931.html) it seems that there is no way to tell the Maven compiler to do so.

---

maven 3.3.9 -
maven-compiler-plugin 3.6.0 -
jdk9-ea+149 -
elasticsearch 2.3.3

Answer (score 3):

After some more testing, I think there are a few options which should tackle many (but definitely not all) 3rd party split package situations.

1. Clean up dependencies - maybe a dependency isn't actually needed or can be replaced by a newer (or more distinct) JAR
2. Restructure your own module into two modules, each reading the package from one of both 3rd party modules (if possible/reasonable)
3. wrap one of the 3rd party modules (or both) in a simple module, which does nothing but explicitly export only the package(s) that are actually needed by your module.

Depending on the situation, one of these options might be a good fit to resolve the split package problem. But none of them can handle situations in which a coherent piece of code actually needs to access classes from both parts of the split package.